# React native webview is Deprecated what is the replacement of webview?

Tags: react-native, webview

React native webview is Deprecated what is the replacement of webview in react native?

i am using expo cli,

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/webview

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) is the community-supported replacement for WebView.